# Database Design: Order Items with quantities spanning multiple statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a requirement to create a database that holds orders with items for each order.

This would be the traditional table setup

#### Order Table

| Id (pk) | CustomerId (fk) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

#### Item Table

| Id (pk) | OrderId (fk) | StatusId (fk) | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1000 |

#### ItemStatus Table

(Don't worry about how the data knows which status is first, second, third, etc)

| Id (pk) | Name | Description | IsStart | IsTerminal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New | For newly created items | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Materials Ordered | For indicating that raw materials are ordered | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Pre-Fabrication | For receiving materials and gathering other resources | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | In Work | For indicating that the assembly process is underway | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | Staging | For preparing the items for shipping | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | Shipped | For indicating that items are complete and no longer in the facility | 0 | 1 |

### However

I have the requirement to take the above quantity of 1000 and break it down by status as it pertains to the business workflow.

My initial implementation looked something like this, but I wanted to reach out and see if there is a better design.

#### Modified Item Table

| Id (pk) | OrderId (fk) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

#### QuantityBreakdown Table

| Id (pk) | OrderItemId (fk) | StatusId (fk) | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 200 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 400 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 200 |

### Edit

Here are some examples in layman terms to help clarify expected solution. All scenarios will be simplified by only having a single item. Also, the handling of ordering materials is out of scope; I just need to know that the item is waiting.

In these examples, we will be handling the creation process of a burger (item #1). In more advanced scenarios, we could add another ITEM such as fries (that would be item #2)

#### Example 1

A restaurant order is created with 1 burger. All materials needed for the assembly of the burger are on-hand; therefore, the burger will progress through the statuses with all quantities (New => Prep => Cooking => Packaged => Delivered).

#### Example 2

A restaurant order is created with 2 burgers. Only enough materials for one burger are on-hand; therefore, the item quantity needs to be split. Since we don't want the customer waiting, the first burger will progress through the statuses with a quantity of 1. While the second burger will have to wait in a new status called Pending. Then once the materials are available, the second burger may continue the workflow.

Comment: The standard design for this is usually Orders Many to Many to Inventory Items which contain the quantities. This Many to many is resolved with an associative table OrderItems which holds both keys. Orders is a child of Customer. Quantities in Inventory and are depleted with each sale in OrderItems and are replenished by Purchase Orders, Requisitions etc. Not sure I understand what the QuantityBreakDown table is used for in your scenario. Your workflow is fine but you probably need statuses which need to rollup to an Order header unless you just have one item per order.

Comment: @Chuma In this case, the Item is specific to the Order in a one to many. Think of it like when you order something in bulk from a retailer. And you place an order for 1000 items. However, they only have 500 on hand. So the retailer will go ahead and ship the first 500 items (their status is Shipped). And then the remaining 500 will need to go through a different set of statuses before arriving to Shipped. I'm looking for a way to manage a single order, with many items that can be partitioned into more than one status

Comment: Ok I see. The way it usually works and maybe that's what your quantity breakdown is trying to do is backorders. On each line of your order items, you have 2 quantities - QuantityOrdered, QuantityShipped. When a client places an order for 1000 it goes to QuantityOrdered, based on availability of Inventory, you put what you have into QuantityShipped, then if you need to create a backorder, you initiate one linked to the order. Those backorders sit there until new stock arrives and then you initiate new orders based on the backorders. Also helps with history.

Comment: @Chuma Ok, we are on the right track, but the requirement is to be able to track the quantities throughout the manufacturing of the order. To expand your comment, I would need to indicate the following: QuantityOrdered, QuantityStep1, QuantityStep2, etc, QuantityShipped.

Comment: ok I see where you are going and understand better what you are trying to do with quantity breakdown. We are talking about the difference between item process workflow for manufacturing and the ordering of finished goods. Your quantity breakdown is the right design and is actually an Item workflow process table used by people on the manufacturing floor. It just keeps track of what step in the workflow an item is in and is read-only on the order item. It likely needs a entry date and exit date so you can figure out how long it has stayed in a particular state and can use to improve metrics.

Comment: You need the original ordered quantity on the Order Item too and unit cost, tax etc. I don't know what you do when you get 1000 and can really only make 500 now and 500 in 2 months. Do you leave it in a workflow step for 2 months or do you have a waiting for materials workflow step? Anyway I think you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Well I cannot just comment to ask for clarifications.

But I would have each OrderItem be its on distinct item in an order with its own Status (status in OrderItem).  So if in fact you had 4 sets of the same item, each would have its own status.

You could always group-by if you want the total # of each OrderItemId

Comment: Well that goes to my point.  The burgers are 2 distinct items in your orderitem table with their own distinct attributes.  Only on orders where everything will always be together and always in the same status could you put together.  On a customer receipt you could still group the burgers togethers on one item if desired.

Comment: My concern for that is scalability. The potential volume could easily reach 3 million records in a year (3000 orders a year, total item quantity averaging 1000 each)